# How to choose a default resource dictionary for xaml in design time?

Tags: c#, wpf

My app have 2 themes (Dark, Light), i created 2 resource dictionaries files for this.

For example:

1) Themes/Dark

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="xxx" Color="#ffffffff" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="xxx1" Color="#ff000000" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

2) Themes/Light

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="xxx" Color="#123456" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="xxx1" Color="#654321" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In some view file im using this color like a:

`Foreground="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=xxx}"`

Before starting app i choose theme like a (abstract example):

```
var rootResources = Application.Current.Resources;
var resDict = new ResourceDictionary () {
    Source = new Uri (path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
};
rootResources.MergedDictionaries.Add (resDict);
```

But in design time in Designer my resource dictionary is not chosen, and i have this problem (screen):
[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcraw.png)

How i can choose resource dictionary for design time?

Added this code to csproj file not working for me

```
<ContainsDesignTimeResources>true</ContainsDesignTimeResources> 
...Condition="'$(DesignTime)'=='true' OR ('$(SolutionPath)'!='' AND...
```